# How to write a Multiple input and logstash filter for hostname based on message field

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

As a newbie to logstash i would like to understand as i have two types of logs one is Linux system logs and another i have CISCO switches logs , now i'm looking forward to create the diffrent `input` and `filter's` for both.

I have defined the `type` for linux logs as `syslog` and for `CISCO` switches as `APIC`  and want to define the and for `filter` section. My CISCO log pattrens sample is as below where my `SWITCH NAME` is 7th Field in the messages , so wonder how to take that 7th field as a Hostname for swiches.

```
Aug 23 16:36:58 Aug 23 11:06:58.830 mydc-leaf-3-5 %LOG_-1-SYSTEM_MSG [E4210472][transition][info][sys] sent user message to syslog group:Syslog_Elastic_Server:final
```

Blow is my logstash-syslog.conf file which is working for syslog but needs while for CISCO logs ie `type => APIC` ..

```
# cat  logstash-syslog.conf
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/*/messages.log" ]
    type => "syslog"
  }
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/Aug/messages.log" ]
    type => "APIC"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp } %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
  if [type] == "APIC" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{CISCOTIMESTAMP} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
   }
 }
}
output {
        #if "automount" in [message] or "ldap" in [message] {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "noida-elk:9200"
                index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                #index => "%{[type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                #index => "%{index}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                #type => "%{type}
                document_type => "messages"
        }
}
```

Filter works correctly for below message and i get the Field  `syslog_hostname` correctly, here in case i get can get the `linuxdev`.

```
Aug 24 10:34:02 linuxdev automount[1905]: key ".P4Config" not found in map source(s).
```

Filter do not work for below message..

```
Aug 24 10:26:22 Aug 24 04:56:22.444 my-apic-1 %LOG_-3-SYSTEM_MSG [F1546][soaking_clearing][packets-dropped][minor][dbgs/ac/sdvpcpath-207-208-to-109-110/fault-F1546] 2% of packets were dropped during the last collection interval
```

Comment: The issue is that the pattern for the APIC section is not the same as for the syslog section. It's a completely different message

Comment: @Val, thanks for your inputs as a newbie learner i'm unable to get it, though i got it somewhat working, i will modify the pattern which i tried.

Comment: A pattern that would work for you is `%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{CISCOTIMESTAMP:time2} %{NOTSPACE:host} (?<prog>[\w._/%-]+) %{SYSLOG5424SD:f1}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f2}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f3}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f4}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f5} %{GREEDYDATA:message}`

Comment: @Val, thx again , let me try this.

Comment: @Val  this works, However in he updated post , this also works bot that elegantely as your `"%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{CISCOTIMESTAMP} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"`   but the only things if we could add ` "%{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} "` into your pattern , i tried but that dont work.

Answer (score 1):

After some grokking here is my pattern for Cisco APIC syslogs:

```
%{SYSLOG5424PRI:initial_code}%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:cisco_timestamp}%{SPACE}%{TZ}%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}%{SPACE}%{URIHOST:uri_host}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGPROG:syslog_prog}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOG5424SD:message_code}%{SYSLOG5424SD:message_type}%{SYSLOG5424SD:messa
ge_class}%{NOTSPACE:message_dn}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message_content}
```

Let me have some feedbacks to improve.